# How to split a string with a string and rearrange it to get folder name in Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Suppose I have "o1usr123" as a computer name.
I need to create a folder "usr-123" if it does not exist and
also use it as a path.

Note: o1usr does not change. Only the number changes.

```
set "String=%ComputerName%"  ::String is "o1usr123"
set "User=%String:*o1=%"
set "Num=%User:*usr=%"
set "FName=%User%-%Num%"

::Determine if FName exist, if not create a folder in ServerPath.
::Then copy files from DATALOG to DATALOG\%FName%

set "ServerPath=\\IYA-PC\DATALOG\%FName%"  ::FName should be "usr-123"
set "ClientPath=%SystemDrive%\DATALOG"
```

Is this correct? Can I turn "o1usr123" to "usr-123" using the code above?
Can you help me on how to determine if FName exist and create a folder if it does not exist.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry @ConnorsFan, I added  the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as indicated, `01usr` does not change,

```dos
set "FName=usr-%computername:01usr=%"
```

That is, the `usr-` prefix followed by the content of the `computername` variable without the `01usr`

Once we have the target folder name

```dos
set "ServerPath=\\IYA-PC\DATALOG\%FName%"
set "ClientPath=%SystemDrive%\DATALOG"    

rem Just try to create the folder (and hide errors if it exist)
md "%serverPath%" 2>nul

rem Try to change to target folder (ensure it exists, maybe it could not be created),
rem copy files and once done restore previous active directory
pushd "%ServerPath%" && (
    xcopy /y "%ClientPath%" .
    popd
)
```

After the `pushd`, a conditional execution operator `&&` has been used. It will execute the code in parenthesis only if the `pushd` was sucessful.